# Arduino button.isPressed() is not working?

Tags: button, arduino, arduino-uno

I am doing one multiple led turn on and turn off with multiple push button and i am using Button library but isPressed condition is not working it's printing all the Serial.println one by one it should print after pressing the button.

I am posting my code please kindly go through it and suggest some solution.

```
#include <Button.h>

Button pBtn1 = Button(2,PULLUP);
Button pBtn2 = Button(3,PULLUP);

/*LED Lights*/
int pL1 = 2;
int pL2 = 3;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

 pinMode(pL1,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(pL2,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  if(pBtn1.isPressed())
  {
     digitalWrite(pL1,HIGH);
     Serial.println("piano1");
  }
  else if(pBtn2.isPressed())
  {
     digitalWrite(pL2,HIGH);
     Serial.println("piano2");
  }
  else
  {
     digitalWrite(pL1,LOW);
     digitalWrite(pL2,LOW);
     Serial.println("no"); 
  }
}
```

In this there are two Buttons and two Led lights are there after pressing one button the led light should glow and after pressing the second button the second one glow but output is little bit strange, all Serial.println executing at one time.

Answer (score 0):

in the above posted code the buttons and leds are on the same pins 2 and 3. They need to be separate pins.

Also being statefull may want to consider using uniquePress() in place of isPressed().

Comment: ok but every time it's going to else part and is there any uniquePress()  return false are there..

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Arduino's internal pull up resistor (and latest Button.h library), instead

```
Button pBtn1 = Button(2,PULLUP);
```

use

```
Button pBtn1 = Button(2,BUTTON_PULLUP_INTERNAL);
```